# Jalopy comments indentation

Tags: java, format, jalopy

We use jalopy to format our code to the sun standard (well 99%).

I have 1 issue with it.  It keeps moving comments to the right of the line.

E.g

```
// Panel
"JPanel.border", new LazyValue(packageName + "PanelBorder"), //frozen

// Button
"Button.background", new ColorUIResource(251, 251, 251), //frozen
"Button.foreground", new ColorUIResource(0, 0, 0), //frozen
```

But jalopy always moves the // Button to the far right.

```
// Panel
"JPanel.border", new LazyValue(packageName + "PanelBorder"), //frozen
                                                             // Button
"Button.background", new ColorUIResource(251, 251, 251), //frozen
"Button.foreground", new ColorUIResource(0, 0, 0), //frozen
```

Is there any way to stop this?

Thanks
Neil

Comment: which version of jaloppy do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so we use jaloppy 1.9.2 (commercial version) and single-line comments are formatted correctly

Answer (score 0):

This is due to *comment association*. You have `//frozen` followed by an empty line and then `//Button`. Jalopy thinks that these two comments are associated with each other, so brings them together.

Take a look at [Section 2.8.13.2 Comment association](http://www.triemax.com/products/jalopy/manual/comments.html) of the manual for more information.